# Content Query Web Part made the ribbon menu dissapper?

Tags: content-query-web-part

I have got a document library to store the documents.

I want to pull data from this library. For this I am trying to use the Content Query Web Part.

But when I click on this webpart, my website is changing: The ribbon menu is disappearing, And so is the Save and Edit buttons. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So What Do I Do If My Content Query Web Part Is Missing?**

There is a SharePoint site collection administration detail that sometimes causes a problem: A user will go to add it the web part to a page and find that the Content Query Web Part is missing. They are sure they are in the Standard or Enterprise edition of SharePoint (as opposed to Foundation), but the web part simply isn’t there. Why? And how do you make it available?

The answer lies in Site Collection Features. The Features are a series of options in SharePoint that can be turned on or off. Some are on by default when a site collection is created; others have to be activated before they can be used. Be aware that sometimes the name and description of a feature doesn’t tell you everything that the feature controls. In this case, the CQWP is part of a bundle of features called SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure. Generally we think of Publishing in SharePoint as a way to enable content management, including combining content with specific page layouts. It’s a feature commonly used by public web sites meant to provide large amounts of information (or frequently changing information) in formats similar to a newspaper or catalog. Activation of the Publishing Infrastructure is necessary, however, to make the CQWP (and certain other web parts) available for use.

A user with **Full Control** or **Site Collection Administrator** permissions can take the following steps to activate the Publishing Infrastructure:
Go to **Site Actions** > **Site Settings**
In the **Site Collection Administration** section, click **Site collection features**

- Go to Site Actions > Site Settings
- In the Site Collection Administration section, click Site collection features

[image]

- On the Site Collection Features page, click the Activate button next
  to SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure.

[image]

Once this feature has been activated, the Content Query Web Part should then be available throughout the Site Collection.

> NOTE: In addition to Site Collection Features that may be activated or
>   deactivated, there are Features that may be turned on or off on each
>   site; this includes the top-level site. If you want to use the full
>   set of Publishing tools, you must also activate the SharePoint Server
>   Publishing site feature on each site/subsite where you wish to use
>   them.

- Go to Site Actions > Site Settings
- In the Site Actions section, click Manage site features

[image]

- On the Site Features page, click Activate for SharePoint Server
  Publishing

[image]

Keep this tip in mind whenever you can’t find a tool or feature in SharePoint – it might just be part of a Site Collection Feature or Site Feature that needs to be activated. In addition, there are some features that are enabled at the server level, so you may need to contact your server administrator if you can’t find it in the Site Collection or Site lists.